# react: call endpoint after each new page render

Tags: reactjs

I have a requirement where a client needs to keep track of which page(s) each logged in user accessed during their login session.  I am trying to find a global way to call a function that will hit an endpoint to perform the tracking.  I would rather have this occur from a level outside of each page but in a way that would give me access to the react path so I know which page is being accessed.  Is this possible in react?

Comment: We can't help diagnose or debug, or make suggestions against, code we can't see. Please edit your post to include a [mcve] for what you are trying to use or accomplish.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose doing something like this would do:

```
const location = useLocation();
useEffect(() => {
  sendTrackingEvent(location.pathname):
}, [location.pathname]);
```

Put this in a Component under the BrowserRouter that is not expected to unmount